# How to remove all endRequest handlers in PageRequestManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to remove all endRequest handlers in PageRequestManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest(endRequestHandler), where "endRequestHandler" is the handler method's name?